# How to fetch data from my API and Vue JS?

Tags: api, vue.js

I have this API result for products - get request:

[image: Picture]

All of my data is inside object "data". **How to** **fetch** these products?

My Vue code:

```
 <tr v-for="product in products" v-bind:key="product.id">
          <td>{{ product.data[1].ID}}</td>
  </tr>
```

But this only gives me data from data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A2ap.png) object. I want to foreach all of these inside "data" array.

Comment: It will work this way:
 <tr v-for="product in products.data" v-bind:key="product.id">
          <td>{{ product.ID}}</td>
  </tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list is nested in some object, you can simply access it from the `v-for` loop

`v-for="product in products.data"`

You can also create a variable, that stores that value directly and then pass this variable to the loop

```
const productsList = products.data;

v-for="product in productsList"
```